# docker-compose - How to specify which network for listening port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using:
`docker-compose 3.7`
`docker engine 18.09.7`

In a docker-compose file, how do I specify which network I want a specific listening port bound to?
For example:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  service-a:
    image: service-a:0.1.0
    networks:
      - network1
  service-b:
    image: service-b:0.1.0
    networks:
      - network1
      - network2
    expose:
      - "8000"
      - "9000"
    ports:
      - target: 8000
        published: 8000
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9000
        published: 9000
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
  service-c:
    image: service-c:0.1.0
    networks:
      - network2
networks:
  network1:
  network2:
```

In this contrived example `service-b` is listening on port `8000` and `9000`.
Is there a way to specify that port `8000` is only accessible on `network1` while `9000` is only accessible on `network2`?

This would be most helpful in the case where a server listens on, say `0.0.0.0` as the host.

Comment: I usually warn people that such questions are not programming questions but OS and server utility questions but not programming questions so your question will get votes for closure.

Comment: Hi @Rob. I appreciate your reply. A -1 doesn't tell anyone what they did wrong. I didn't know my question was off topic here. I can see your point about the category of question. Though I'm not really dealing with an OS and I'm not really dealing with a server either so I could also see the philosophical argument that I'm merely asking a question about the features of the docker-compose IDL, which to me might feel more like programming than network IT stuff. I see merit to both sides.

Comment: It's a problem discussed on meta. That it's often difficult to tell whether such questions are programming, OS or server configuration related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I get this right what you want to achive is to grant `service-a` access to port `8000` of `service-b` but block any access from `service-a` to port `9000` of `service-b`. And the same for `service-c` but the other way around?

For this you first need to know how the networking with `docker-compose` works: for each network under the `networks` section `docker-compose` (in this case) creates a virtual network connecting a virtual network device of the host machine to it as well as a virtual network device of each container contected to the network. Each of these virtual devices can communicate directly with each other in the same virtual network while the different virtual networks are usally isolated from each other.

The `expose` keyword now does not actually *expose* any ports but instead only *documents* the intent that a process will listen on that port(s). You can examine this information about a container using `docker inspect`. Besides the added *meta-data* `expose` does not actually do much more, see [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). So in this case it has no real use.

The `ports` keyword on the other hand does expose the listed ports to ports **on the host machine** - [see the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose). Since the containers communicate directly via their share networks this is again not of real use for your scenario.

There are also no other configuration options which are intended to limit the communication of containers within the same network, i.e. there is no officially supported way to do this nicely.

One way to do this would be to modify the application *itself* to not listen on `0.0.0.0` with each port but only bind to the address of the respective network (`network1`/`network2`). But this requires application-specific changes and to somehow detect the correct address for each port.

Another way would be to inject your own `iptables` rules to block undesired access between containers, [see the docs on this](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/). The downside of this is that it has to be done completely outside of `docker` and `docker-compose`.

And lastly there is this hackish solution: instead of blocking undesired access only allow for explicitly whitelisted ports:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  service-a:
    image: service-a:0.1.0
    networks:
      - network1
  service-b:
    image: service-b:0.1.0
    networks:
      - network2
    ports:
      - 172.101.0.1:8000:8000
      - 172.103.0.1:9000:9000
  service-c:
    image: service-c:0.1.0
    networks:
      - network3
networks:
  network1:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.101.0.0/24
  network2:
  network3:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.103.0.0/24
```

This works by assigning **each** container to its very **own network** completely isolating them from each other. But for `network1`/`network3` we explicitly configure the subnet so we know the gatway IPs (`172.101.0.1`/`172.103.0.1`) of them which are assigned to the virtual network devices **of the host**.

Now we can "expose" the ports `8000`/`9000` of the `service-b` container to these host IP addresses, i.e. port `8000` on `172.101.0.1` will be forwarded to port `8000` of the `service-b` container. `172.101.0.1` belongs to the host but is part of `network1` and thus can be accessed by `service-a` allowing it to only access that one port of `service-b`.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking because I may not have control over which host/adapter the server listens on and was wondering if there was a docker-level solution. It looks like there is a way, but its not ideal. Thank you for sharing the information.

Comment: I have tried that and i get an error. see shorturl.at/svEMT 
Do you need to use external network or to configure the networks with specific options?