# docker : how to open a port on a specific ip? Error starting userland proxy: cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker

I have thise two networks in my docker compose and i would like docker to open a port only on one of the network the container is connected to.

I have therefore specified an ipam to my network and an ip on the open port following this post :[docker-compose - How to specify which network for listening port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403674/docker-compose-how-to-specify-which-network-for-listening-port)

But then i get the error :

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx (ffa5c03d45d2e985c8caf76449ae8920f8fd59aeb6aa8618c300bfc1204a480c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 172.101.0.2:80: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

I am running docker with a nsremap so the docker process is not root but when i sudo docker compose up i get the same error.

Any idea where the issue can come from?

Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
---
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    cpus: 0.5
    mem_limit: 400m
    container_name: nginx
    cap_drop:
      #- CHOWN #Disables the ability to change file ownership and group ownership
      - DAC_OVERRIDE #Disables the ability to bypass file and directory read, write, and execute permission checks
      - DAC_READ_SEARCH #Disables the ability to bypass file and directory read permission checks and to search directories with execute permission
      - FOWNER #Disables the ability to override file ownership and group ownership
      - FSETID #Disables the ability to set the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits on files
      - KILL #Disables the ability to send signals to any process or process group
      - NET_RAW #Disables the ability to use raw IP sockets
      #- SETGID #Disables the ability to set the effective group ID
      #- SETUID #Disables the ability to set the effective user ID
      - SETPCAP #Disables the ability to set the process capabilities
      - SYS_CHROOT #Disables the ability to change the root directory
      - SYS_MODULE #Disables the ability to load and unload kernel modules
      - SYS_PTRACE #Disables the ability to trace processes with ptrace
      - SYS_RAWIO #Disables the ability to perform raw I/O operations
      - SYS_TIME #Disables the ability to set system clocks and timers
      - SYS_TTY_CONFIG #Disables the ability to configure tty devices
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
#      - "172.101.0.2:80:80" #Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx (0f129795c4d99edafa4ba4d0b29845d1abad26e3ee3bf635ddb549831191d8cf): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 172.101.0.2:80: bind: cannot assign requested address
      - "80:80"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      backend:
      web:
        ipv4_address: 172.101.0.2
  app:
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cpus: 0.5
    mem_limit: 400m
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /logs/app:/app/logs
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  app_volume:
    name: app_volume
networks:
  web:
    name: web
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.101.0.0/24
  backend:
    name: backend
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.102.0.0/24
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Normally, if you're using Docker's internal networking setup, you wouldn't manually specify any IP addresses, and there's no way to make ports only accessible to some networks.  If you need to access the container from outside Docker, Docker networks aren't involved, but the Compose `ports:` setting can specify a host IP address on a multi-homed system.

Comment: i do not agree, the iptables settings modified by docker clearly state the ip and port of the container exposed in docker compose. I want to specify on which network it is exposed.
I will add the docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file tries to use `ports:` to specify a Docker-internal IP address.  You can't do that.  It sounds like you're trying to use functionality like `ports:` within the Docker-internal network environment, and that's not possible at all.

There are two networking mechanisms in play here:

1. Docker has an internal networking system.  Containers internally happen to have individual IP addresses, but you almost never need to know or specify these.  Instead, you can use a container's name as a DNS name, and connect to the container's "normal" port.
2. If you need to connect to a container from outside of Docker, then you need to specify `ports:`.  That has an optional IP address part, but it specifies a *host* IP address, not a container address.

So say you have some sort of "gateway" system that has both a public interface 10.20.30.40/16, and also a private interface 192.168.73.1/24.  When you run a container, you could specify `ports: ['192.168.73.1:80:80']` to publish a container on only the internal network but not the external network.  To reiterate, this is a *host* address that you've already configured using `ifconfig` or a similar mechanism.

For connections between containers, you have no options to selectively publish or remap ports.  In your example, assuming the `nginx` main container process listens on port 80, `http://nginx` will reach it from any other container on the `backend` or `web` networks.  `ports:` aren't required or used here; there is no option to change the port number, or to only listen on one network but not the other.

The minimum change you need to make is to delete the problematic `ports:` line; you don't need (and can't use) `ports:` to control the Docker-internal network.

Comment: then what's the point to define multiple networks in docker compose if i cant publish a port on only one of these networks?

Comment: IME, for things where the set of containers fits into Compose, there's no point in having multiple networks, and correspondingly there's no benefit to manually declaring `networks:` at all.  You can just delete all of the `networks:` in your Compose file and use the `default` network Compose provides for you.